How to Resolve ArgumentParser Conflict with -h/--help in Subcommands?
I'm developing a Python command-line tool using argparse with multiple modules, each having its own set of arguments. I'm using separate classes to define each module's arguments and integrate them into a main script. However, I'm encountering an issue where the -h/--help argument is conflicting when running the help command for a subcommand.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
fastp_arguments.py:
import argparse

class FastpArguments:
    def __init__(self, args=None):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="fastp arguments.", add_help=False)
        self.args = args if args is not None else []
        self._initialize_parser()

    def _initialize_parser(self):
        fastp_args = self.parser.add_argument_group("Fastp Options")
        fastp_args.add_argument("-i", "--in1", required=True, help="read1 input file name")
        fastp_args.add_argument("-o", "--out1", required=True, help="read1 output file name")
        fastp_args.add_argument("-I", "--in2", help="read2 input file name")
        fastp_args.add_argument("-O", "--out2", help="read2 output file name")

    def parse_arguments(self):
        self.args = self.parser.parse_args(self.args)
        return self.args

main.py:
import argparse
from fastp_arguments import FastpArguments

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My Tool', add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', help='Show this help message and exit')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='tool', help='Sub-command help')

    fastp_args_class = FastpArguments()
    fastp_parser = subparsers.add_parser('fastp', help='Fastp Help', parents=[fastp_args_class.parser], add_help=False)
    fastp_parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', help='Show this help message and exit')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.tool == 'fastp':
        fastp_args_class.args = args
        fastp_args_class.parse_arguments()
        print("Fastp selected")
        print(fastp_args_class.args)
    else:
        parser.print_help()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Issue
When I run seqsightqc fastp -h, I get the following error:
argparse.ArgumentError: argument -h/--help: conflicting option strings: -h, --help

What I've Tried
Setting add_help=False for the parent parsers.
Manually adding the -h/--help argument to both the top-level parser and subparsers.
Desired Outcome
I want to be able to run seqsightqc fastp -h and see the help message for the fastp subcommand without any conflicts or errors.
Question
How can I resolve the argparse conflict with the -h/--help argument when using subcommands in this setup?
Specifically, I want the final out of -h to print all the arguments of all the modules!

add_help=False just means -h and --help aren't added automatically to a parser. But you are then explicitly adding both options to every parser; that's the source of the conflict.

Normally the subparsers are created with with -h/--help, and usage that's based on the main usage.  You can observe that in simple subcommand setup.

If you omit the fastp_parser.add_argument... line, do you get the conflict?  If not, what sort of help?  You could also look at fastp_parser.usage and fastp_parser.__actions__

IN an ipython session I create your class, and the parser object from main.
The basic help is then:
In [14]: parser.parse_args(['-h'])
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] {fastp} ...

My Tool

positional arguments:
  {fastp}     Sub-command help
    fastp     Fastp Help

options:
  -h, --help  Show this help message and exit

ANd the fastp help:
In [15]: parser.parse_args(['fastp','-h'])
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py fastp -i IN1 -o OUT1 [-I IN2] [-O OUT2] [-h]

options:
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit

Fastp Options:
  -i IN1, --in1 IN1     read1 input file name
  -o OUT1, --out1 OUT1  read1 output file name
  -I IN2, --in2 IN2     read2 input file name
  -O OUT2, --out2 OUT2  read2 output file name

That's how I expect.
If I omit both the the add_Help=False and the add_argument('-h', '--help'..., I get the same thing.
So I'm not sure what's your problem.  As long as the parent, FastpArguments omits the help, you shouldn't have this conflict.  Whether you use subparsers or not, using parents requires at least one add_help=False.
